# Hiding a Column in a Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

```
 if (typeof dataTable_leads == 'undefined') {
    dataTable_leads = $('#GlTable').dataTable({

    "bDestroy": true,
    "bRetrieve": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bDeferRender": true,
    "aaData": dataset,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "aaSorting": [
        [5, 'asc']
    ], //desc

    "columnDefs": [
                   { "visible": false, "targets": [0] }
                 ],
```

My datatable is working properly. But am trying to hide first column in my table. But its not working.Am using ColumnDefs datatable property here but its not working. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

i think this will help you. add this line after your datatable is load.

```
table.column( 0 ).visible( false );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide columns by this command:

```
fnSetColumnVis( 1, false );
```

Where first parameter is index of column and second parameter is visibility.

Via: http://www.datatables.net/api - function fnSetColumnVis

It may help you.

Comment: This is perfectly working. Thank u so much for your help @ Harsh Sanghani

Comment: Welcome :) Please vote to answer and make correct if its useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding a column requires somethign like this (API [Doc](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ 2 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            },
            {
                "targets": [ 3 ],
                "visible": false
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Hence your columnDefs should be strictly as follows:

```
"columnDefs": [
                {
                    "targets": [ 2 ],
                    "visible": false,
                    "searchable": false
                },
                {
                    "targets": [ 3 ],
                    "visible": false
                }
            ]
```

To see the exact error that's happening, open up the developer tools in your browser and see the error log to see any errors that is happening.